# ACRO package list same style as table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms, acro

I'm having trouble using the ACRO package. In particular with the styling of the `printacronyms` list.
I want the list to have the same style as the table of contents. Compare the following two pictures:
[image: Table of contents]

===================================================================
[image: Acronyms]

I want the dots in the `printacronyms` list (second picture), to have the same style as in the
table of contents (first picture). The minimal code to produce the above is the following:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt
]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acro}

\acsetup{
  make-links,
  pages/display = first,
}

\DeclareAcronym{cms}{
  short = CMS,
  long = Content Management System,
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printacronyms
\newpage

\chapter{Title}
\section{Section 1}
\ac{cms}
\section{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

I tried setting `list/template = lof` or `list/template = toc` in the `\acsetup` but that wont compile for me, even though thats how it's documented [here](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/acro/acro-manual.pdf#page=14&zoom=100,118,769). I'm using ACRO version 3.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does “wont compile for me” mean exactly? Does it give errors? And if yes, which one is the first error? Is your tex distribution up to date? Many times people tell acro wouldn't work because they updated the package only instead of the whole distribution.

Comment: If you suspect a bug please report it via acro's issue tracker

Comment: I'm using MiKTeX for windows SetupVersion: 20.6.29 and CurrentVersion: 20.7. When I compile with `list/template = toc` in `\acsetup` for example, I get something about: `Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \TemplateName 
                         
l.23 
     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., '\hobx'), type 'I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., 'I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the relevant part in the definition of `\@dottedtocline` in the LaTeX kernel

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\dotsfill{%
  \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
}
\makeatother
```

and set `acro`'s option `pages/fill` accordingly:

```
\acsetup{ pages/fill = \dotsfill }
```

With your example this gives

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt
]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acro}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\dotsfill{%
  \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
}
\makeatother

\acsetup{
  pages/fill = \dotsfill ,
  make-links,
  pages/display = first,
}

\DeclareAcronym{cms}{
  short = CMS,
  long = Content Management System,
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printacronyms
\newpage

\chapter{Title}
\section{Section 1}
\ac{cms}
\section{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, have not tried this out but will soon.